# Objeto aparece em determinado lugar da página

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: eu quero/preciso de um código para meu site, que funcione da maneira [deste site](http://eufacoprogramas.com/). Nele, quando o usuário usa o *scroll* do mouse para descer um pouco na página, uma setinha (que quando é clicada, volta para o **topo** - *a parte de cima do site*) aparece no canto direito.

**Já pesquisei no *Google***, e acho que não soube usar as palavras corretas, pois não achei nenhum resultado que me atendesse.

Obs.: O código para voltar *para cima* eu já tenho.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilize jquery + css.
Coloque a seta dentro de uma div e aplique o css para que fique a flutuar sempre do lado direito, por exemplo:

```
<div class="seta"><img src="/imagens/seta.jpg" /></div>
```

O seu css ficaria da seguinte forma, partindo do princípio que seta tem 30x30:

```
.seta {position:fixed; display:none; right:0px; top:300px; width:30px; height:30px; z-index:999;}
```

Agora utilize jquery para esconder ou mostrar a div quando o scroll atingir uma certa posição. Para isso vamos utilizar o evento "scroll" do jquery:

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
    nScrollPosition = $( window ).scrollTop();
    if(nScrollPosition>=100){
         $( ".seta" ).css( "display", "block" );
    }else{
         $( ".seta" ).css( "display", "none" );
    }
});
```

No exemplo acima, quando o scroll atingir 100px do topo, a seta irá aparecer, caso contrário esconde a seta.

Comment: +1. Acrescentando: para obter o mesmo efeito da página de exemplo, basta animar a exibição/ocultação da seta (usando por exemplo `fadeIn`/`fadeOut`) em vez de somente atribuir a propriedade CSS.

Comment: @mgibsonbr é verdade, me esqueci do efeito.

Comment: De qualquer forma, a questão principal foi respondida.

Comment: Cara Mutio Obrigado, muito Obrigado Mesmo!! +1 , e se eu podesse +1000

Comment: Eu quase que concordo totalmente contigo. O ponto é que para isso se usa `position: fixed` e não `absolute`

Comment: @AndréFigueiredo tens toda razão, mas penso que ele já possuía o css feito, só necessitava do javascript.

Comment: ok! +1 de qualquer maneira! :)